# LWJGL - Interleaved VBO isn't working as intended

Tags: java, lwjgl, vbo

so I've been playing around with the LWJGL and made a 3D space that creates a number of cubes with random velocities and colours, originally using two VBOs (one each for location and colour).

I'm trying to make it work with a single, interleaved VBO, but my attempts so far result in the cubes being draw with 'flashing' colours and multiple colours per cube when they should be single, solid colours. It looks like it's an error to do with the starting position and stride for the vertices/colours but changing them around doesn't appear to help, or causes some very strange effects.

Here's the code from the class creating the VBO (there shouldn't be any errors elsewhere since it works fine with the non-interleaved version and they contain equivalent methods):

```
package test3D.first.main;

import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;

import test3D.first.entities.*;
import test3D.first.main.threads.Updater;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.*;

public class InterleavedDrawer {

private int vboHandle;
private static FloatBuffer drawData;
final static int vertexSize = 3;
final static int colorSize = 3;
final static int normalSize = 3;
private static int vertexQuantity;

public InterleavedDrawer() {

    initialise();

}

private void initialise() {

    drawData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(0);

    vboHandle = glGenBuffers();

    updateBuffers(Updater.objects);

}

public void draw() {

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboHandle);
    glVertexPointer(vertexSize, GL_FLOAT, 1, 0L);
    glColorPointer(colorSize, GL_FLOAT, 1, 4L);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexQuantity);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

}

public void update() {

    for (int i = 0; i < Updater.getObjectQuantity(); i++) {

        drawData.put(Updater.objects.get(i).getVertices());
        drawData.put(Updater.objects.get(i).getColors());

    }

    drawData.flip();

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboHandle);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, drawData, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

}

public void clear() {

    drawData.clear();

}

private void updateBuffers(ArrayList<AbstractEntity> objects) {

    vertexQuantity = 0;

    drawData.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {

        vertexQuantity += objects.get(i).getVertexQuantity();

    }

    drawData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertexSize * vertexQuantity + colorSize * vertexQuantity);

}

}
```

As I said, I suspect the error comes from the lines:

```
glVertexPointer(vboHandle, GL_FLOAT, 1, 0L);
glColorPointer(vboHandle, GL_FLOAT, 1, 3L);
```

Leaving the values as they are causes the odd flashing effects, changing the long value in the glColorPointer() to 4 strangely creates 'regions' within the cubes that are colours corresponding to (0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0) etc., which makes no sense whatsoever since the colours are entirely random floats, and any other values I've tried don't seem to do anything other than the first effect. Am I misusing the values here or something else? Any help at all would be very much appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stride & offset are specified in bytes. So the stride should be 6 floats * 4 bytes = 24 and the offset 0 (vertex) and 12 (color) respectively.

Also there's a mistake in update(). Right now vertex and color data are interleaved like this (assuming a single triangle per object):

```
( object 1  ) ( object 2  )
V1V2V3 C1C2C3 V4V5V6 C4C5C6 ...
```

Where V# is a vector (x,y,z) and C# is a color (r,g,b).
OpenGL expects them in this order:

```
( object 1   ) ( object 2   )
V1C1 V2C2 V3C3 V4C4 V5C5 V6C6 ...
```

So the body of the update loop should be changed to something like this (not tested)

```
float[] vertData = Update.object.get(i).getVertices();
float[] colorData = Update.object.get(i).getColors();

for(int j = 0; j < vertData.length; j += 3) {
   drawData.put(vertData, j, 3)
   drawData.put(colorData, j, 3)
}
```

[More information](http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Using_Vertex_Buffer_Objects_%28VBO%29)

Comment: I tried using those values, but it just results in a black screen - any combination of values below 24 and 12 just gives crazy visuals... any idea why this is? Thanks for the input so far :)

Comment: There's a problem with the interleaving of the vertex/color data. I've updated my answer.

Comment: That's fixed it! Thank you so much, I just wasn't aware of quite how OpenGL expected the buffer to be formatted, you've helped a lot :) Have a nice day!